# Google Analytics - Count unique visits based on distinct custom var instead of session

Tags: session, google-analytics, unique, analytics, visitor-pattern

I'm setting up a website where I have to track unique visitors during a certain period. The problem is that GA uses a cookie to determine the visit count of a user. This means that a computer/browser in a shared environment will track two different users that use the same browser as one. Since every user had his own guid I was thinking of using this a way to determine unique visits. Is there a way to determine the distinct amount of visits based on a custom var?

---

I' actually looking for a way to make this work without cookies. Because cookies can be removed. I'm actually looking for a way to merge multiple visit entries using the custom var guid.

I could do this using the GA data and some kind of program that removes duplicates but I would like to implement this using GA build in segment options.

Answer (score 0):

What about having a set of GA cookies for each guid? You could write some JavaScript that maintained multiple sets of `__utm` cookies and put them in place at appropriate times so that GA picked up the cookies relevant to the current guid.